# A word for newbie or fresher sounds similar to abrecrombie

Tags: word-usage, word-request

While watching season 1 or 2 of Arrow I heard the word. I can not search the word as I do not recall or can not spell exactly. What I know is pronunciation of that word has resembled abrecrombie and word mean something to call a new guy or newbie or fresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abercrombie. It's not exactly a widely used word that means 'newbie' or 'fresher' generally. The character is given that nickname because he is like the young men who the clothing company Abercrombie & Fitch uses as models and store employees.

[Why does Sin call Roy “Abercombie”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27473/why-does-sin-call-roy-abercombie)